# textarea input (html form) isn't echoed by php script. why?

Tags: php, html, forms, input, textarea

```
<form method='POST' id="myform" action='process-input.php'>
    <textarea form="myform" name='inputtext' id='inputtext'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'> 
</form>
```

The input of inputtext isn't echoed by process-input.php, which looks like this:

```
echo $POST_['inputtext'];
```

why?

Comment: Shouldn't that say $_POST['inputtext']?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be

```
echo $_POST['inputtext'];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $_POST['inputtext'];
```

you got your underscore wrong

Answer (score 2):

You need to change it to $_POST['inputtext']

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong, it should be :

```
$_POST['inputtext'];
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of PHP post is `$_POST`,

You need change `echo $_POST['inputtext'];` instead of `echo $POST_['inputtext'];`